# ossec email alerts

Tags: security, gmail, alerts, ossec

Just installed ossec and sendmail however can't able to get alerts to my gmail from ossec. I am able to see the alerts on the sendmail localhost, however alerts seem to be not forwarding to gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that you are able to send an email from your sendmail to your gmail?

It is probably a sendmail problem. General debugging:

- check your mail.err
- check your mail.log
- Gmail: does your IP have a reverse dns entry?
- Does your ISP block outgoing traffic on the SMTP port? (25)

In `/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf` Do you see your email address listed there?